# Removing formatting from a spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I am using ColdFusion to read a spreadsheet, but it has a problem if the cell is formatted as a fraction.

Q: Is there a way to automatically remove formatting to a spreadsheet once the user has uploaded it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you process a worksheet, run this **VBA** macro on it:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Cells.ClearFormats
End Sub
```